# Cut data by date for multiples of break="min"

Tags: r, aggregate, xts

I'm using R to aggregate tick data and I have the following function which works well to aggregate the data to the minute but now I want to expound on that and aggregate to 5, 10, 15min.  How can I do that?

```
SPY <- aggregate(as.numeric(SPY$PRICE), list(min = cut(index(SPY), breaks="min")), mean)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question with the `xts` tag...

You can use `period.apply` for this.  The following will give you the mean of every 5 minutes:

```
period.apply(SPY$PRICE, endpoints(SPY, "minutes", 5), mean)
```

Comment: I was just writing the same thing. +1 for speed.